# childviewcontroller of UINavigationController stored in NSArray crashes on ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, nsarray, hashtable

I have code to fetch the perticular childviewcontroller of navigation controller.

```
NSArray *contllrs = [self.navigationController childViewControllers];
NSLog(@"controllers : %@",contllrs);
 if([contllrs count]>3)
           [self.navigationController popToViewController:[contllrs objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

It gives log as

```
childviewcontrollers : NSHashTable (%@) {
[3] <abcVC: 0x1dc1d0>
[4] <defVC: 0x5daf790>
[7] <efgVC: 0x1724a0>
[10] <adsfVC: 0x1b14f0>
[11] <SdfVC: 0x1e2c30>
}
```

Crashes with

```
InvalidArgument
```

This works fine with iPad simulator but crashes on iPad

Comment: not sure if it is a typo but you are missing the close parenthesis on your IF statement. it should not even compile as far as i can tell.

Comment: It was just one line in IF so i didn't put parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the below code:

```
    NSArray * viewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    if([viewController count] > 3)
    {
        UIViewController * vc = [viewController objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
```